# How to display No results found message on Search using Javascript only?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display "No Results Found" in the case where someone uses my search feature to search for something that returns no results.

Currently it does not display any text if no results found. **The problem is I am unable to update the HTML code, but can only update Javascript. So cannot add empty div for the message into the HTML code.**

Please see the code below. Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```css
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list" title="Search forms list"></p>

<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>abc</td>
<td>xyz0</td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>test12</td>
<td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>abctd <td>
<td>09/30/2019</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>abctd </td>
<td>06/30/2019</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What about appending an empty div via Javascript for the message?

Comment: yes, that can work. I am not sure how to do it. I am a beginner in javascript

Comment: Maybe check the documentation for [appending elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

Comment: Or use `alert()` box if modal popup is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job keep doing these great things
your question is smart and I have your answer

add this script to your javascript and html files

```js
    function myFunction() {
            const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
            const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
            let arr = []
            for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                const h = document.getElementById('h1')
                const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
                tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
                if (tableRows[i].getAttribute("style") === "display: none;") {
                    arr.push(tableRows[i])
                    if (arr.length === tableRows.length) {
                        h.innerHTML = "Not found"
                    }
                } else {
                    h.innerHTML = ""
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list"
            title="Search forms list">
    </p>
    <h1 id="h1"></h1>
    <table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>xyz0</td>
            <td>03/30/2017</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>test12</td>
            <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
            <td>03/30/2017</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th> New Column</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>abctd
            <td>
            <td>09/30/2019</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th> New Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>abctd </td>
            <td>06/30/2019</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

if you want the code with one file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list"
            title="Search forms list">
    </p>
    <h1 id="h1"></h1>
    <table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>xyz0</td>
            <td>03/30/2017</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>test12</td>
            <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
            <td>03/30/2017</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th> New Column</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>abctd
            <td>
            <td>09/30/2019</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th> New Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>abctd </td>
            <td>06/30/2019</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <style>
        table.table_brdr td {
            padding: 8px 10px;
            border: none;
        }

        table.table_brdr th {
            background-color: #a6a6a6;
            color: black;
        }

        tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background-color: #D3D3D3;
        }

        #myInput {
            background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
            background-position: 10px 10px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 20%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
            const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
            let arr = []
            for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                const h = document.getElementById('h1')
                const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
                tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
                if (tableRows[i].getAttribute("style") === "display: none;") {
                    arr.push(tableRows[i])
                    if (arr.length === tableRows.length) {
                        h.innerHTML = "Not found"
                    }
                } else {
                    h.innerHTML = ""
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```